# wordpress custom fields multiple data

Tags: custom-field

i need help with wordpress custom fields currently i store date in one custom field called audio using the "," and "$" example:
name, link $ name, link $ etc
i have managed to use the data and split the data using php in my theme i.e the playlist.
i just need help in creating a custom metabox with 2 text fields that can be duplicated by clicking on adding more and two more fields would show. i only want to use only one custom field to store the data.

thanks

Comment: I don't understand this question at all. Why are you storing the date in a field called audio? Why not use multiple custom fields instead of trying to implement your own serialisation? What 2 fields do you want to show when you click on a button?

Answer (score 1):

You can store an array in a custom field; WordPress serializes it for you on save and unserializes it on get.

Name your fields with a pseudo array syntax:

```
<input name="mycustomfield[audio]">
<input name="mycustomfield[date]">
```

You’ll get a `$_POST` array:

```
mycustomfield = array ( 'audio' => 'somevalue', 'date' => 'somedate' )
```

Now you can do whatever you want with it.

Drawback: Meta queries against serialized arrays are hard. Multiple post meta field are much easier to handle.